# open file for each element in array and check against a regex Perl

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, io

I have an array filled with 4 digit numbers (@nums) that correspond 
to conf files which use the numbers as the file name, like so: `0000.conf`

I am reading a file `foreach` element in the array and checking
the file for a pattern like this :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $num (@nums) {
    open my $fh, "<", "$num.conf"
      or warn "cannot open $num.conf : $!";
    while(<$fh>) {
        if (/^SomePattern=(.+)/) {
            print "$num : $1\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I am extracting the part of the pattern I want using `()` and the 
special var `$1`.

This seems to be working except it only prints the results of the last file
that is opened, instead of printing the results each time the foreach loop
passes and opens a file, which is what I expected.

I am still learning Perl, so any detailed explanations of what I missing here
will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are errors like `Global symbol "$num" requires explicit package name at..` How do `.conf` files look like?

Comment: you are missing the closing } for the while loop for starters

Comment: sorry for the typos I have declared "$num" with `my` and I do have the closing bracket for the while loop both in my original code and I added them here. The .conf files area few hundred lines each. I know that "/^SomePattern=(.+)/" is in each file.

Comment: do you get any errors? try changing warn to die to see if not-closing $fh at the end of the loop is problematic

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, so .conf files should be questioned.

Comment: try `print if /^SomePattern/;` as this would print the entire line.  You may need to adjust the regex for capturing.

Comment: no errors. It just prints the results for the last file that opens. I can remove that file and it will print the results for a new last file.

Comment: does it print ALL the results from the last file, or it prints only the last result from the last file?

Comment: You sure you need Perl for this? In Linux you can do it with `find` and `grep -Po` right from shell...

Comment: The biggest difference I see between your "example" code and @Davs  answer, is Davs specifies how `@nums` comes to be.

Your code does not, and `@nums` is a magical value that comes from nowhere, and as such, your code is not "complete".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use v5.16;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @nums = qw/ 0000 0200 /;

for my $num (@nums){
    open my $fh, "<", "$num.conf" or die;
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        if( /^somePattern=(.+)/ ) {
            say "$1";
        }
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

this seems to be working for me..You are missing the close $fh; in your code, maybe that is wrong. Secondly, maybe only one of your files matches you regex, check the content for typos. I myself don't use foreach, maybe you are missing 'my' before $num. Depending of your regex, it might be useful to strim newline characters from the end of line with 'chomp'.

Comment: Perl will automatically `close` the old file when a new file handle is assigned to `$fh`.  Good point about the regex.  `for` is just 'short' for `foreach` (Perl parses the former as the latter).  Use `chomp` not `chop` to remove the input record character (usually `\n`), but that wouldn't matter here since `(.+)` wouldn't match `\n` in the OP's regex.

Comment: yeah, chomp should be used, not chop, that was a typo.

Comment: I rewrote my code like your example, and it is working now... Still not sure of the exact problem with my code though.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is excellent for a learner.

The problem is that, using `"$num.conf"`, you are trying to open files named `0.conf` etc. instead of `0000.conf`.

You should also use the value of `$!` in your `die` string so that you know *why* the open failed.

Write this instead

```
my $file = sprintf '%04d.conf', $num;
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Unable to open '$file': $!";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have left my previous answer as it may be useful to someone. But I missed your opening *"I have an array filled with 4 digit numbers"*.

Doubtless you are populating your array wrongly.

If you are reading from a file then most usually you have forgotten to `chomp` the newline from the end of the lines you have read.

You may also have non-printable characters (usually tabs or spaces) in each number.

You should use [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper) or the better and more recent [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDump) to reveal the contents of your array.

Comment: my @nums array looks something like this :
$VAR = [
        '0000',
        '0001',
        ];

Comment: Are you populating it in the program like that? There is *no difference* between `my @nums = ('0000', '0001')` and `my @nums = qw/ 0000 0001 /` except that the latter is designed to be easier to type. If you don't show the assignment to `@nums` then we can't really help you.